# Whats the best linux console tool to explore sound file information?

Tags: linux, command-line, mp3

Im looking for console tool that will output most detailed information about sound file (particularly mp3).

Tried to use different tools (id3, lame, ffmpeg)

Looking to get such info:

- Format (Mp3/Wave/etc..)
- Encoder
- Bitrate
- Compression
- Stream size (not filesize)

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I use **mplayer -identify filename**

It works with almost any audio/video file.

Comment: +1 for naming a piece of software that might already be installed.

Comment: Actually, even `file` can produce useful details about audio/video files. This is certainly installed on most Linux systems.

Comment: When called on webm files, it does not identify them, and even worse, it starts playing random noise from the speakers! This is `mplayer 1.1-4.8` from `Linux Mint 17.3`

Answer (score 4):

There is also a `sox` based tool - [`soxi`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxi.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en). I use this on Windows (although not restricted to) and it's pretty comprehensive at what it does.

Comment: This is the one that worked best for me (on Linux Mint 17.3 for webm files)

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg-based: [ffprobe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffprobe/)

Answer (score 1):

I used a few years back this little tool called mp3info and I was pleased with it.

You can get it here: http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info/